# Aligning different parts of a text string to left and right side of div

Tags: html, css, razor, css-float

I have added a chat window to my current project which uses razor. The problem I am having is that when a new line occurs its shifting everything to the left... A screenshot of the problem is [image: capture] the red line shows where the highlighted text should be aligned-right.. The current code that displays this area looks like this:

```
<div id="messages" class="rectangular-area" style="text-align: left; width: 600px;">
<h3>
    Latest received events:
</h3>
 @For Each item In xList
   If item.Contains("System Message") Then
       @<br />@<b style="color: Red">@item.Split("-")(0)  - <b style="color: Black">@item.Split("-")(1) : <b style="color: #8B6508">@item.Split("-")(3)</b></b> </b>
   ElseIf item.Contains("*******@******online.com") Then
       @<br />@<b style="color:#00CDCD">@item.Split("-")(0) <b style="color: Blue">(@item.Split("-")(1)) <b style="color:Black"> : @item.Split("-")(2)</b></b></b>
   ElseIf item.Contains("************") Then
      @<br />@<b style="color:#00CDCD">@item.Split("-")(0) <b style="color: #E066FF">(@item.Split("-")(1)) <b style="color:Black"> : @item.Split("-")(2)</b></b></b>
   ElseIf item.Contains("************") Then
       @<br />@<b style="color:#00CDCD">@item.Split("-")(0) <b style="color: #66CDAA">(@item.Split("-")(1)) <b style="color:Black"> : @item.Split("-")(2)</b></b></b>
   Else
        @<br />@<b style="color:#00CDCD">@item.Split("-")(0) <b style="color: #FFA54F">(@item.Split("-")(1)) <b style="color:Black"> : @item.Split("-")(2)</b></b></b>
   End If
Next
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this feat? I have tried using align-left in the third `<b style>` of every type and that does not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That markup with the inline styles is pretty hard to deal with, so here is a simple example in plain HTML and CSS that you can learn from:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <strong>User 1</strong>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong>User 2</strong>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.</p>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong>User 1</strong>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>        
    </li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS**

```
strong, p {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EF2E9/)